# Hyper-Vでエクスポートエラー

Tags: windows

Hyper-Vである仮想マシンをエクスポートしようとするとエラーになります。
正常にエクスポートできるマシンもあります。

チェックポイントが多いマシンをエクスポートしようとするとエラーになる傾向があるように思えます。
原因や解決策をご存じの方はいますでしょうか？

**画像のパスの部分は消してあります。**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]